# Use Matrix Block as footer

Tags: matrix

My site is built on a single structure section called "pages". It includes 4 entryTypes.

One of the entryTypes is called "contact" and includes a MatrixBlock that displays fine on the contact page.

I'd like to make use of those entries (from the Matrix Block) in the site's footer (on all pages). Here is where I started:

```
{% for block in entry.MatrixFieldHandle.type('MatrixBlockHandle') %}
{{ block.title }} etc...
{% endfor %}
```

This only works on the contact page itself. How can I display a Matrix Field elsewhere than on its own page?

Answer (score 3):

First you need to get the correct entry. Based on what you write, you can get it in any template by doing:

```
{% set contactPageEntry = craft.entries.section('pages').type('contact').first() %}
```

Then you should be able to loop over your matrix field like this:

```
{% for block in contactPageEntry.MatrixFieldHandle.type('MatrixBlockHandle') %}
    {{ block.title }} etc...
{% endfor %}
```